# Xeon, Linux and turbo boost technology

Tags: central-processing-unit, intel, activation, boost

I have 4 core Xeon at my server and Debian, the CPU has turbo boost technology. Does the top command in linux show % cpu usage counting with the possibility of turbo boost ?

I mean if I have 50% CPU usage does it mean I use half of the CPU with turbo boost included or I use 50% of the CPU's basic clock ?

Also at which CPU usage is the turbo boost activated ?

Comment: Seems quite complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost#Example What Xeon model do you use?

Comment: I use Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1231 v3 @ 3.40GHz

Comment: CPU usage is sampled, not absolute.  Also turbo is only available when not all cores are busy.  Therefore I'm not sure what use any CPU utilisation metric is, when the system is not maxed out, nor what value you'd want to see displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so because Turbo is not accounted.
That's the reason why I've programmed a Top CPU monitoring software to show Intel Turbo Boost in action based on the Cores states.
Compile CoreFreq, run it, and watch each core dropping from green to red when usage is above 100%
Instructions @ https://github.com/cyring/CoreFreq